# Могу ли я использовать xmlns тег без префиксов/постфиксов?

Tags: xml, атрибуты, jaxb

Я написал класс A с атрибутом xmlns.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
    private String xmlnsAttr;

    public String getXmlnsAttr() {
        return xmlnsAttr;
    }

    public void setXmlnsAttr(String xmlnsAttr) {
        this.xmlnsAttr = xmlnsAttr;
    } 
}
```

Если изменить имя этого аттрибута (скажем, на 'a'), то все работает нормально. Но мне нужен атрибут с имененм 'xmlns'. При его использовании я получаю ошибку

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", local:"A"). Expected elements are <{}A>
```

Код теста:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
   StringReader reader = new StringReader("<A xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"></A>");

   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

   Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   A a = (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
   assert a.getXmlnsAttr() != null;
}
```

Что можно исправить? Я искал в сторону [XmlScheme](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html), но мне это мало помогло: в лучшем случае у меня добавлялся постфикс.

Comment: Это не атрибут. Это идентификатор пространства имен. Что Вы хотите с ним делать?

Comment: Создать атрибут с именем xmlns невозможно, т. к. это [зарезервированный](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) атрибут. Задайте своему элементу пространство имён и этот атрибут появится автоматически.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Мне нужно парсить xml-объект, где элемент содержит xmlns. Пример такого объекта представлен в Example 27 на https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/.